# Calling the same function multiple times on the same data but different arguments using purrr

Tags: r, purrr

I'm trying to call the same function multiple times on the same data but with different function arguments.
My problem can be described as:

```
x <- as.character(1:5)
l <- list(list(name = "a", collapse = ""), list(name = "b", collapse = "-"))
output <- list()

for(l_cur in l) {
  output[[l_cur$name]] <- x %>% paste(collapse = l_cur$collapse)
}
```

Is there any cleaner way to do it using `purrr`?
(Background: I want to use this with `rvest` because I'm calling `html_nodes()` on the same data multiple times but I'm only changing `css` argument.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably , you can use :

```
library(purrr)
map(l, ~x %>% paste(collapse = .x$collapse)) %>% set_names(map(l, pluck, "name"))

#$a
#[1] "12345"

#$b
#[1] "1-2-3-4-5"
```